# Excel Macro Query: Hiding Rows based on cell value

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I've tried the below code but it doesn't seem to be working can anybody help me. I just want to hide rows 3 & 4 when B1 has the text `Delete`. But I want this to run automatically when `Delete` is entered into B1.

Thanks

[image: Code]

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please review the following post and update the question appropriately, making sure any code is included in the question and include and errors receiving:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please don't include code as images. Include it as text and format it as codeblock so it is much easier for people to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work

```
Option Explicit 'Very first line to ensure that variables are declared

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'check if target address is B1
    If Target.Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False) = "B1" Then
        ShowHideRows
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub ShowHideRows()
    If Range("B1").Value = "Delete" Then
        Rows("3:4").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Rows("7:8").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    ElseIf Range("B1").Value = "Open" Then 'use ElseIf if possible like here
        Rows("3:4").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Rows("7:8").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
End Sub
```

**Note:** This is case sensitive. So if you type in B1 `delete` instead of `Delete` it will not run. To make it non case sensitive use `LCase()` like:

```
LCase(Range("B1").Value) = "delete" 'string delete must be lower case!
```